# <script> template directive angularJS pass variable

Tags: angularjs

I need to include the script tag inside one of my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ptag_params = {
zone: "transaction",
transactionId: "Transaction Id",
currency: "Currency",
customerId: "Your customer ID",
siteType: "Site Type",
};
</script>
```

I have tried using a directive like so:

```
'use strict'

angular.module 'myApp'
.directive 'kwankoScript', ->
  restrict: 'E'
  replace: true
  scope: 
    transactionId: "="
    userId: "="
  template: '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ptag_params = {
    zone: "transaction",
    transactionId: {{ transactionId }},
    currency: "EUR",
    customerId: {{ userId }},
    siteType: "d"
    };
    </script>'
```

This doesn't work because I cannot evaluate `{{ transactionId }}` and `{{ userId}}` from within a script tag. Whereas it works great when I use a div in the template.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Bro, you should use ng-init in this case. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: thanks dude ;-) can you be a bit more specific ?

Comment: Why does that JS need to be inside a template at all? It just set an object on the global scope which can be done from the directive in JS instead of using the directive to inject a script tag to run some JS.

Comment: All you doing here is initializing the div or container with some predefined values. For that no need to get to directive complexity. use <div ng-init="info={zone: "transaction",
transactionId: "Transaction Id",
currency: "Currency",
customerId: "Your customer ID",
siteType: "Site Type",}. > ... </div>

Comment: @Peterson so you think I could do this from the view ? even within a <script> tag ?

Comment: Bro, don't use the script tag. Get initialized data and use 2 way binding by defining a model and glue or change your values on that basis.